# VirtualBox: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes Error

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am trying to run a Virtual Machine of Ubuntu, but I get an error on start up:[image: The Error Pop-up Screen]

According to the error message, it is an error in the BIOS. Is there a way to access it and fix this error?

Edit: On Windows 10, I've been trying to access my BIOS. I have held down Delete at Start Up along with the new method with UEFI. I still cannot find a solution.

Comment: It is not an error in the BIOS, it is a request to enable VT-x in the BIOS. Did you try? And are you using a CPU that supports VT-x in the first place?

Comment: @techraf Since I have a Gigabyte motherboard, I must hold Delete on startup. I have done that but since I have Windows 10, they replaced the start up BIOS with the UEFI interface. My i7-3820 3.60GHz 4 Core processor supports VT-x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to your BIOS and enable VT-x, assuming your CPU supports it. If it doesn't, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Can you please extend that answer? My i7-3820 does support VT-x.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Unfortunately, I can't tell you the BIOS access key without knowing your computer. What computer do you have? If you tell me that, I can add detail.

Comment: I am using a Gigabyte motherboard, so it is Delete when I start up. I have an i7-3820 3.60 GHz 4 Core processor with a Zotac GeForce GTX 970 Amp! Extreme Core Edition, 16 GB of RAM, a 128 GB SSD (where Windows is installed), and a 2TB hard drive. Thought you might as well have my specs.

Comment: You need to enable VT-x in the BIOS. Just search through the pages for VT-x or "virtualization". Enable it.

Comment: The problem is I cannot access the BIOS via Startup.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Well then your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu; it has to do with your motherboard/BIOS. Sorry, but this isn't the right place to ask for help on this.